# How to show an indicator when an item has been added to a folder in a document library (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: document-library

I have a requirement to show some sort of indicator when an item has been added to a folder in a document library. At the item level, SharePoint has the "New" indicator. This does not seem available at the folder level. Is this true?

I tried to use the column "Modified", but this seems to be specific to the folder as well, rather than the items in the folder.

Can someone help me through this, or provide some alternatives? If my assumptions above are incorrect, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chap has a couple of blog posts regarding changing the folder icons, I guess once you find a method you can do something to extract the created date and work out if a different icon should be displayed or not:

http://mattstark.blogspot.com/2010/02/sharepoint-folder-icon-changer-json.html

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new view that is sorted by modified date and in the "Folder" section of the view configuration select "Show all items without folders"

This will create a flattened view of the library with all the recently modified files shown.

Not exactly what you asked for but maybe its useful.

Comment: Well, I would need to still show the library with the folder structure.