# Display New! against a folder

Tags: new-indicator

I have multiple folders that many people can upload documents into.  How can I show at folder level that a new document has been added please? I want to be able to see New! next to the folder.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5536/how-to-show-an-indicator-when-an-item-has-been-added-to-a-folder-in-a-document-l